management.call_command как запустить из отдельного .py файла
Пытаюсь выполнить тестирование management функции Django, если я вызываю команду из консоли: python3 manage.py read_all_news - работает как ожидается, но при попытке вызвать команду внутри функции в файле testing.py - выдает ошибку, что команда не найдена.
testing.py
from django.core import management

def readNews():
    news = management.call_command('read_all_news')
    return news

print(readNews())

Traceback:
  ...

  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 112, in call_command
    raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'read_all_news'

